# How can I include e.g., in citep

Tags: natbib

When I reference some work, currently I get something like *(Jimmy and Tan, 2003)*. I want an updated `\citep` where I can use *(e.g., Jimmy and Tan, 2003)*. I should be able to call either the earlier reference such as, *(Jimmy and Tan, 2003)*, or the updated citation *(e.g., Jimmy and Tan, 2003)* at will. How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: As you mention `\citep` I assume you use `natbib`, the `cite` package doesn't define that.

Comment: yes I am using that. The solution works. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Note that you can mark questions as solved by accepting the most helpful answer. This is done by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can add prenotes and postnotes to the site with the optional arguments:

```
\citep{dude}
\citep[p. 42]{dude}
\citep[e.g.][]{dude}
```

See page 7 in `natbib`s manual.

When using only one optional argument (one pair of `[]`), that becomes a postnote, when using two the first one is a prenote, the second a postnote.

Comment: is there a way to do that using \cite only?

Comment: @AndréCytryn The default implementation of `\cite` only has the postnote, but for example the `natbib` implementation has both pre- and postnote. So if you're using `natbib` you can do exactly as in my answer. If not, the answer will depend on the setup you're using, so please ask a new question and include a minimal example (see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) that shows how you're doing things.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer by Torjørn T., given that the "e.g., Author, year" format is quite common, one can conveniently define a \citeg command (to be inserted before the \begin{document}) as

```
\newcommand{\citeg}[1]{\citep[e.g.,][]{#1}}
```

which automatically produces the prenote "e.g.,".

Comment: Though—just since it may not be obvious to a user who doesn’t know this method—this new command can only be used to add “e.g.” without a page reference.