# Add the word "from" in a citation with a new \cite command

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, citing, apacite

I would like to add the word "from" in the citation when I based myself on the work of the researchers I cite e.g. **(from Lander et al., 2001)**

Maybe with a new command in order to have 2 types of citations, with "from" and the normal one.

I am using the report class, the package `apacite` and a basic bib file.

I know it is possible to create my own style but I just wanted to know if there is a simple way to create this without entering into details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add "from" in only a few citations, you could work with a prenote. The `\citep` command allows to add prenotes and postnotes, see for example [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166410/how-can-i-include-e-g-in-citep). So you could use`\citep[from][]{lander}`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `apacite` package, use simply `\cite<whatever>{whatheverAgain}` and that's it